# Regex for highlighting phrase inside string

Tags: php, regex, cpu-word, highlight, phrase

I had made this algorithm to highlight a word inside a string, but I must adapt it to also highlight a phrase.

What I had was a function that loop word by word, trim unwanted characters and replace using `\b($str)\b`.

I made that way so I could trim `",.-"`, etc.., for example, but that's not a good solution for phrases (not even for words).

How could I achieve this for phrases as well?

An example: suppose I have to highlight `adipiscing elit` in this string:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
```

It must become:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur <span>adipiscing elit</span>.
```

Comment: @machineaddict Please try to just say what you mean. If you need a snippet of code to help OP, then why not just say that? We've all been newbs, and sarcasm has never helped anyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand well but try this:

```
\b(adipiscing elit\b\W?)
```

and replacement string:

```
<span>$1</span>
```

Output in regexstorm.net:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur <span>adipiscing elit.</span>
```

Comment: Thank you, @walid! It helped a lot, but it happens I've made a little mistake on the question: how can I leave the dot [.] outside the span as well?